# How to read an unknown number of float values from a STRING

Tags: c, scanf

I have a string that has unknown number of float values separated by a white space.(something like this):
**12.55 54.11 -1.00000 2.222 ...**
Now i need to read all those values into an array.
How do I do this? Do I have to use **sscanf**?

Comment: Please chose C++ or C. Please also have a go.

Comment: So, drop the C++ tag since the "right" way to do this in that language and its standard library has *nothing* to do with `sscanf` ?

Comment: @ASHUTOSH great. next up, the documentation for [**`sscanf()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) may come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to use `sscanf`?

No, you do not have to, unless you prefer to use it. I would prefer using [`strtof`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html).

Regardless of the function that you use, you would need to use a loop that reads the values from the string. Since the number of items is unknown, you could scan the string twice - once to learn how many items you have, and a second time to do the actual read. Since the string is in memory, the wasted time in the loop that counts the entries will not be significant.

```
int cnt = 0;
char *str = "2.55 54.11 -1.00000 2.222";
char *ptr = str, *eptr;
do {
    strtof(ptr, &eptr);
    ptr = eptr;
    cnt++;
} while (*eptr);
printf("%d\n", cnt);
float *res = malloc(cnt*sizeof(float));
ptr = str;
for (int i = 0 ; i != cnt ; i++) {
    res[i] = strtof(ptr, &eptr);
    ptr = eptr;
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != cnt ; i++) {
    printf("%f\n", res[i]);
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/z4zmtl)

Comment: "Since the number of items is unknown, you could scan the string twice"- How?

Comment: @ASHUTOSH Scan it the first time in a loop, then start from the beginning. Take a look at the code, around the `ptr = str` line.